# Как через цикл foreach пройтись по массиву указателей?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

        animals.Add(new Dog("Vovka", 12));
        animals.Add(new Dog("Ura", 0));


        foreach(Animal el in animals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(); //What should I write?????
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Animal
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected virtual void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public int happy { get; set; }
    public int Happy
    {
        get
        {
            return happy;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value>10)
            {
                happy = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                happy = value;
            }

        }
    }
    public Dog(string name,int happy) : base(name)
    {
        Happy = happy;
        print();
    }
    protected override void print()
    {
        base.print();
        Console.WriteLine("Happy:");
        Console.WriteLine(happy);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Запустить эти два объекта еще раз с помощью списка.

Comment: вместо `Console.WriteLine(); //What should I write?????` вызывай `print`: `el.print()`

Comment: @Grundy и сделать `print` публичным ещё.

Comment: Вы взяли чей-то код и пытаетесь его довести до ума или в чём проблема поставить вызов необходимых функций в нужное место?

Comment: @alexolut, точно. не обратил на это внимание :)

Comment: @Grundy а компилятор обратил :)

Answer (score 1):

> Console.WriteLine(); //What should I write?????

Напишите

```
Console.WriteLine( el );
```

в для классов перегрузите функцию `toString`.